# Thomson's Plum Pudding and Rutherford's scattering

Tags: particle-physics, atomic-physics, scattering, atoms

Why did Rutherford's scattering experiment disprove the plum pudding? Assuming a gold-atom to be a large homogeneous ball and hitting it with small homogenuous $\alpha$-balls should lead to the actually observed scattering angle distribution, why would anyone assume that the $\alpha$-particles would go *through* the gold-atom (am I right that back then the idea was that the gold atom is indeed a more or less solid ball)?

Comment: Well, the plum pudding model did not exactly have a 'large homogeneous ball' - it was a bunch of protons hanging around in the general vicinity of each other, so an alpha particle would scatter off of individual protons. Further, questioning why somebody would assume something we all know now really doesn't help understand how we got to actually know it...

Answer (score 0):

[wiki:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_scattering)
At the time of the experiment, the atom was thought to be analogous to a plum pudding (as proposed by J. J. Thomson), with the negatively-charged electrons (the plums) studded throughout a positive spherical matrix (the pudding). If the plum-pudding model were correct, the positive "pudding", being more spread out than in the correct model of a concentrated nucleus, would not be able to exert such large coulombic forces, and the alpha particles should only be deflected by small angles as they pass through.

However, the intriguing results showed that around 1 in 8000 alpha particles were deflected by very large angles (over 90°), while the rest passed through with little deflection. From this, Rutherford concluded that the majority of the mass was concentrated in a minute, positively-charged region (the nucleus) surrounded by electrons.